# how can i correct my python code to convert binary string into position specific code

Tags: python, binary

```
def convertSeq(s, index):
    result = [i+1 for i,ch in enumerate(s) if ch=='1']
    result = ' '.join([str(index)+':'+str(i) for i in result])
    result = str(index)+' '+result
    return result
seq1 = "00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000"

a = convertSeq(seq1, 1)
print a
```

Given functoin has been created to convert

```
"00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000"
```

into position specific code its work fine if i use

```
seq1 = "00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000"
```

as input for the code I get,

```
 1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65
```

as output (as expected). But when I used an input file with the contents:

```
00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000 
10000000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000 
00100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000
```

the output is very weird.

To me it seems that when i use

```
seq1="00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000"
```

it is considered a string because of `" "` and when I use a input file so it considers `0` and `1` as individual charactera.

What method should I use so that it can take binary code input from a file containing binary code in lines and generate output for each and every line.

Sample Input:

```
00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000
10000000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000
00100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000
00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000
10000000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000
00100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000
```

Sample Output:

```
1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65
2 2:1 2:21 2:44 2:64
and so on...........
```

As I am very new in programming I have spent my 5-6 hours on it but not succeeded.Please help

Comment: You've already written the code. What do you expect us to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the file using `enumerate()` to count the lines:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line_no, seq in enumerate(f, start=1):
        print convertSeq(seq, line_no)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `convertSeq` works then this should do:

```
line_num = 1
for line in open(filename):
    print convertSeq(line, line_num)
    line_num += 1
```

Comment: Great its nicely working,  if these (00001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000) lines are output of a function and rather storing it in a file i directly want to use function    convertSeq(s, index) so that its directly generate output 1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65  so what would be the changes in given code thanks a lot

Comment: @ mshsayem 
Great its nicely working, if these (0000100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000‌​0) lines are output of a function and rather storing it in a file i directly want to use function convertSeq(s, index) so that its directly generate output 1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65 so what would be the changes in given

Comment: If the input string (say `st` from a function) contains newline characters (`\n`) then you can call `st.split('\n')`, enumerate the resulting list and then call `convertSeq`. ... I am a bit confused what you really want..

Comment: @ mshsayem actually this code is working fine but first i convert ACDE into  this  0000100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000‌​0 with a script and save to it  in a text file now i have to run next script what  u have write for me  to get the out put "1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65" i just want a single code rather doing this task with two different code. is it possible

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this, read the whole file as string and pass to your function

```
def convertSeq(s, index):
    result = [i+1 for i,ch in enumerate(s) if ch=='1']
    result = ' '.join([str(index)+':'+str(i) for i in result])
    result = str(index)+' '+result
    return result

# read the sequence from file
with open ("file.txt",'r') as f:
   f_seq=f.readlines()

for line, seq in enumerate(f_seq, start=1):
    a = convertSeq(seq, line)
    print a
```

From the content you have given, it gives following output

```
1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65
2 2:1 2:23 2:43 2:63
3 3:3 3:23 3:43 3:63
4 4:5 4:25 4:45 4:65
5 5:1 5:23 5:43 5:63
6 6:3 6:23 6:43 6:63
```

You can also read the file name as arg to your program, so you don't have to hard code file name

```
import sys
def convertSeq(s, index):
    result = [i+1 for i,ch in enumerate(s) if ch=='1']
    result = ' '.join([str(index)+':'+str(i) for i in result])
    result = str(index)+' '+result
    return result

#take the file name as arg
seqFile = sys.argv[1]

with open (seqFile,'r') as f:
   f_seq=f.readlines()

for line, seq in enumerate(f_seq, start=1):
    a = convertSeq(seq, line)
    print a
```

Comment: I missed the line number part from your questions, so you can use enumerate() as suggested by @Duncan. Updated my code to reflect it

Comment: cool, please consider accepting answer if this is what you were looking for

Comment: actually this code is working fine but first i need to convert ACDE into this 0000100000000000000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000100000000000000‌‌​​0 with a script and save to it in a text file now i have to run next script what u have write for me to get the out put "1 1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65" i just want a single code rather doing this task with two different code. so i want to know what whould be the code if rather write  binary string in file i directly save it in a variable and will directly get the out put  1:5 1:25 1:45 1:65

Comment: what is the other script, is that python?? sorry but what is ACDE??

Comment: @ DevC yes its python script                                          bin_dict = {
'A':'10000000000000000000',
'C':'01000000000000000000',
'D':'00100000000000000000',
'E':'00010000000000000000',
'\n':''
}                                                                  def binary_conv(sequen):
        a = ("".join([bin_dict[l] for l in seq]))
        return a                                                           for seq in lines:
    a = binary_conv(seq)
    print a