# Trouble with python code, i have write down one code to enumerate binary code and want to remove the spaces from the output

Tags: python

I have write down a python code given bellow, i was trying to make same changes to remove the space from out put but its not working for me :

```
text = "000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000100000000000001010000000000"

result = []

for item in enumerate(text):
    i, ch = item
    if ch == '1':
        result.append(i+1)
x = result

for i in xrange(len(x)):
    print i+1,':',x[i],
```

output of this code is:

```
1 : 24 2 : 37 3 : 45 4 : 56 5 : 66
```

i want to make some changes so that i could produce output like this:

```
1:24 2:37 3:45 4:56 5:66
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
for i, x in enumerate(result, start=1):
    print '{}:{}'.format(i, x),

#output: 1:31 2:52 3:66 4:68
```

And instead if using `xrange(len(x))` for indexing use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

`enumerate` also allows us to provide the `start` index, so the first loop in your code can be changed to:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(text, start=1):
    if ch == '1':
        result.append(i)
```

Comment: @user2935002 what course is this btw? I've seen this a few times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490082/how-can-i-correct-my-python-code-to-convert-binary-string-into-position-specific